# Calculate sum of rows and add subtotal per group using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe with sales amounts across years and months. When I do a pivot table on it, I get the grand total but not the subtotals per yer. This is my original dataframe:

```
          SalesAmount  Year     Month
0        3.649034e+05  2011   January
1        4.276324e+05  2011  February
2        9.557190e+05  2011     March
3        9.736942e+05  2011     April
4        4.374198e+05  2011       May
```

After a pivot table operation like this,

```
pd.pivot_table(df,
        values=['SalesAmount'],
        index=['Month', 'Year'],
        columns=[],
        aggfunc=np.sum,
        fill_value=None,
        dropna=True,
        margins=True,
        margins_name="Total",
        cart_product=False,
        observed=True
    )
```

This is my current dataframe:

```
Month    Year     SalesAmount             
January  2011      3.649034e+05
         2012      5.641538e+05
         2013      1.509512e+06
         2014      1.910565e+06
         2015      9.558356e+05
...                         ...
December 2016      5.264493e+06
         2017      6.511821e+05
         2018      1.321238e+06
         2019      5.010637e+06
Total              2.065793e+08
```

What I need is to add a row called subtotal after every month, with the sum of SalesAmount for the group of years per month. Is there a pandas way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First create `MultiIndex DataFrame` with aggregate `sum` and with level `Year` with `All` values, add to original, for correct ordering months is used ordered catgorical, so possible last sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.drop('Total', level=0)
         .groupby('Month')
         .sum()
         .assign(Year='All')
         .set_index('Year', append=True))

df = pd.concat([df, df1])

months = ['January','February', 'March',  'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
          'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'Total'] 

categories = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.levels[0],
                                 categories=months,
                                 ordered=True)
df.index = df.index.set_levels(categories, level='Month')

df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
               SalesAmount
Month    Year             
January  2011     364903.4
         2012     564153.8
         2013    1509512.0
         2014    1910565.0
         2015     955835.6
         All     5304969.8
December 2016    5264493.0
         2017     651182.1
         2018    1321238.0
         2019    5010637.0
         All    12247550.1
Total          206579300.0
```

Comment: I solved it in a similar way here, but with two levels of sums : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77694716/7018268